# Perfmon not logging to SQL Server

Tags: logging, perfmon

I'm trying to use an established Data Collector Set to start loggging perfmon counters to a local SQL Database (on a local SQL instance). However, here's what my current setup looks like:

[image: Current Configuration]

And when I try to run the Data Collector Set I get the following error:

```
Call to SQLAllocConnect failed with %1.
```

So I think my Data source name might be formatted incorrectly, but I can't find anything good in TechNet to walk me through that. I've created the db "PerfMon" in the SQL instance and made sure that the user running the logging has DBO rights to that database (and is also sysadmin). There's only one SQL instance on this box so I shouldn't have to specify that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Only windows authentication works when PerfMon uses odbc to store data in SQL server.
So it will not help to create additional SQL-Logins, better use a Windows Domain Account.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by:

In the ODBC system DSN configuration on the SQL Server, click "Client Configuration", this opens the "Add Network Library Configuration" dialog box. Make sure that "Dynamically determine port" is NOT checked.

In SSMS, add [NT Authority\SYSTEM] as a windows login and make sure it has write access to the database you have defined in the above ODBC system DSN.

Hope it helps someone.

Paul